Checking for a Keypress to Pause a Program Midway through a loop in Python
I am currently creating a web scraper to collect data for a project I am working on. However, the scraper I am using uses a Selenium Webdriver and Pyautogui, meaning that I can't really use my computer while it is active. What I would like to do is have a function to pause my program with a keypress (or something else simple) when I want to use my computer for other things, then resume my program with a simple input.
The problem I am encountering is that I want this pausing to happen at the beginning of every loop of my program. This loop takes a long time and checking for a keypress wasn't working how I was intending it to. This also does not have to be a keypress. I just want a way to stop my the code from running so that I can do other tasks during the day, then let the code run while I am not at my desk. Here is a similar example of what I am trying to achieve:
import time

paused = False

def observe_keypress_function():
    if key_was_pressed:
        print('Key has been pressed')
        paused = True

while True:
    if paused:
        input('Waiting for input')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

this is the output I am looking for given a keypress during the loop
1
2
3
4  # Between 4 and 5 is a keypress
Key has been pressed
5
6
7
8
9
Waiting for input

Obviously, this doesn't need to be a function like this, but I want this to be what happens.
I tried using the keyboard library, but it didn't work for me. I also thought threads might be useful. That way I could detect the keypress at any time, then just wait until the loop completes to pause. However I have not played around with this enough to say if this would work or not (nor do I have that much experience with threads).
Thank you so much for the help!

if you want to stop in every loop then maybe add in loop input("Press ENTER to continue")

as I remember keyboard or pyinput can create listener which works in separate thread and it doesn't stop rest of code.

you have to check if paused: inside loop for i in range(1, 10):

inside observe_keypress_function you have to use global paused to inform function that has to assign value to external variable paused. Current code assign value  local variable paused which doesn't change external variable paused

Modules keyboard and pynput should already use threading to run listener so it doesn't need to use threading manually.
But I see two mistakes in your example.

you have to check if paused inside loop for i in range(1, 10):

inside observe_keypress_function() you have to use global paused to inform function that it has to assign value to external/global variable paused. Current code assign it to local variable paused and it can't change external variable paused



Full working example with module pynput
I used key which still exists on some keyboards Pause/Break but you can use other key for this.
It needs to press ENTER in console to continue.
In last example I show how to use key to pause and unpause code without input().
from pynput import keyboard
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_press(key):
    global paused  # inform function that it has to assign new value to external variable `paused`

    #if key == keyboard.Key.space:
    if key == keyboard.Key.pause:  # special key `Pause/Break`
        print('Key PAUSE pressed')
        paused = True

# --- main ---

paused = False

# before program
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()  # it starts thread with listener

# program

while True:
    print('New Loop')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
        if paused:  # at the end of loop
            input('Press ENTER to continue')
            paused = False  # set it back 

# after program             
listener.stop()  # it stops thread with listener
listener.join()  # wait for end of thread


Full working example with module keyboard
I also used key Pause/Break
import keyboard
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_press():
    global paused  # inform function that it has to assign new value to external variable `paused`

    print('Key PAUSE pressed')
    paused = True

# --- main ---

paused = False

# before program
keyboard.add_hotkey('pause', on_press)  # special key `Pause/Break`

# program 

while True:
    print('New Loop')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
        if paused:  # at the end of loop
            input('Press ENTER to continue')
            paused = False  # set it back 
            
# after program            
# ... nothing ...


Example which uses the same key Pause to pause and unpause.
It needs while paused: instead of if paused: input(..)
import keyboard
import time

# --- functions ---

def on_press():
    global paused  # inform function that it has to assign new value to external variable `paused`

    print('Key PAUSE pressed')
    paused = not paused  # switch `True` and `False`
    print('Paused:', paused)  # show current 

# --- main ---

paused = False

# before program
keyboard.add_hotkey('pause', on_press)  # special key `Pause/Break`

# program 

while True:
    print('New Loop')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

        while paused:  # wait for end of pause
            #print('.', end='')  # to show that it doesn't crash
            time.sleep(1)  # use less CPU when paused
            
# after program            
# ... nothing ...

If main code has to display text when it paused then you can add `if paused
while True:
    print('New Loop')
    for i in range(1, 10):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)

        if paused: #  to print text only once
            print('Loop Paused')
            while paused:  # wait for end of pause
                #print('.', end='')  # to show that it doesn't crash
                time.sleep(1)  # use less CPU when paused
            print('Loop Unpaused')


A very simple multithreading approach below. Just uses a listening thread and a couple of shared events for pausing and stopping the whole thing. Emulates working periods by sleeping during 10 uninterrupted seconds. Stops when 'q' is input
import time
from threading import Thread, Event

pause_event = Event()
stop_event  = Event()

def listener():
    while True:
        s = input()
        pause_event.set()
        if s.lower().startswith('q'):
            stop_event.set()
        if stop_event.is_set():
            break

def main():
    listenthread = Thread(target=listener)
    listenthread.daemon = False
    listenthread.start()
    pause_event.clear()
    stop_event.clear()
    while True:
        if stop_event.is_set():
            break
        if pause_event.is_set():
            pause_event.clear()
            pause_event.wait()
            pause_event.clear()
            continue
        time.sleep(10)
    stop_event.set()
    listenthread.join()

main()

